# How to turn on and off the scroll trigger in Material UI useScrollTrigger module?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, survey, scrolltrigger

I'm trying to create a survey page using Material UI in React. I'd like my survey to turn on when the user scrolls over a question and turns off when the user scrolls out of a question. A behavior similar to this page.

https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/Typical-Customer-Demographics-Template

After doing some research, I decided to use useScrollTrigger module in MUI. I was able to turn on the questions when I scroll down to them, but still can't figure out a way to turn them back off when I scroll down, out of them.

This is how I created my scrollToColor function:

```
import { useScrollTrigger } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function ScrollToColor(props) {
  const {
    threshold,
    threshold2,
    textColorBefore,
    textColorAfter,
    fadeIn,
    fadeOut,
    children,
    ...other
  } = {
    threshold: 50,
    threshold2: 100,
    textColorBefore: "gray",
    textColorAfter: "black",
    fadeIn: "0.1s ease-in",
    fadeOut: "0.1s ease-out",
    ...props,
  };

  const trigger = useScrollTrigger({
    disableHysteresis: true,
    threshold: threshold,
    target: props.window ? window() : undefined,
  });

  const trigger2 = useScrollTrigger({
    disableHysteresis: true,
    threshold: threshold2,
    target: props.window ? window() : undefined,
  });

  return React.cloneElement(children, {
    style: {
      color: trigger ? textColorAfter : textColorBefore,
      transition: trigger ? fadeIn : fadeOut,
      color: trigger2 ? textColorBefore : textColorAfter,
      transition: trigger2 ? fadeOut : fadeIn,
    },
    ...other,
  });
}
```

I created 2 triggers so when it scrolls to the question, the text color turns black and when scroll out, it turns back to gray. This is a sample code on how I added this to the parent component.

```
import {
  AppBar,
  Toolbar,
  Typography,
  ThemeProvider,
  CssBaseline,
  createMuiTheme
} from "@material-ui/core";
import ScrollToColor from "./ScrollToColor";

const NavbarscrollToColor = props => {
  const theme = createMuiTheme();

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />

      <ScrollToColor>
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Toolbar>
            <Typography variant="h5" noWrap>
              {props.title}
            </Typography>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </ScrollToColor>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default NavbarscrollToColor;
```

But this unfortunately doesn't work. Any tips on how to make this work?

Also, is there any easier and cleaner way in React I could have archived this other than using the MUI useScrollTrigger module?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After spending more time on this issue, here is the solution that I came up with that works:

```
import { useScrollTrigger } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function ScrollToColor(props) {
  const {
    threshold,
    threshold2,
    textColorBefore,
    textColorAfter,
    fadeIn,
    fadeOut,
    children,
    ...other
  } = {
    threshold: 0,
    threshold2: 100,
    textColorBefore: "gray",
    textColorAfter: "black",
    fadeIn: "0.3s ease-in",
    fadeOut: "0.3s ease-out",
    ...props,
  };

  const trigger = useScrollTrigger({
    disableHysteresis: true,
    threshold: threshold,
    target: props.window ? window() : undefined,
  });

  const trigger2 = useScrollTrigger({
    disableHysteresis: true,
    threshold: threshold2,
    target: props.window ? window() : undefined,
  });

  return React.cloneElement(children, {
    style: {
      color: trigger && !trigger2 ? textColorAfter : textColorBefore,
      transition: trigger && !trigger2 ? fadeIn : fadeOut,
    },
    ...other,
  });
}
```